# Multiple action.class.php

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, web-frameworks

I do have an module e.g. account. Of course you will find a file called in acount/actions/action.class.php.

The PHP-file action.class.php is getting big. Is it possible to extend it?

for an example:

```
/account/action/action.class.php
/account/action/action2.class.php
```

If it is possible, how does the code look like in action.class.php and in action2.class.php? And/or where should I enter something in a config-ymal-file?

Thanks in advance!

Craphunter

Comment: Are you following the MVC pattern? Would be odd to end up with too much code if you are. Refactor rather than splitting across multiple class files like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Symfony actions can be declare in two flavors:

1. A big actios.class.php file that inherit from sfActions
2. Multiple xxxAction.class.php file that inherit from sfAction

The are both basically the same but these cant be mixed (you must decide if you want 123123 files, 1 per action, or one big fat file).

Here its the symfony reference on this matters: [Symfony Front Controller - Actions](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_alternative_action_class_syntax) check the Action section.

Comment: Your link points to the docs of the outdated 1.0 version. Here's the link for symfony 1.4: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_alternative_action_class_syntax

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the action class is getting too big because you have too much stuff in it. I would suggest breaking it into multiple modules or moving relevant parts of the logic code into your models.

Adding an include for an action2 file is not how Symfony 1.4 is intended to be used and will likely just lead to all kinds of other headache.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't support 'partial classes' like C#. So you have two options:

- Create an inheritance chain, by creating a `baseActions` class which inherits from `sfAction`. Then create your `MainActions` class which inherits from `baseActions`. You can add different layers of inheritance.
- Group functions in seperate classes. Override the `execute()` function in your actions file, and manually call the function on the class you need.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider if some of the behavior you're implementing in the *action* (controller) belongs to the *model* (or the view) instead. If the really belongs to the action just follow guiman's advice and create an action per class inheriting `sfAction`.

If I have a CRUD *module* based on a *model* (as generated by the CLI), and I have to define additional behaviors for that *model*, I tend to create another *module* to contain that behaviours. E.g., considering a *model* `Article`. I could create an `article` *module* for the CRUD behaviors (generated), `article_support` for additional behaviors like moderation, activation, etc. and perhaps `article_ajax` for async requests.